# Which other Real Analysis textbooks unusually advise ending delta-epsilon proofs with a cluttered $\epsilon?

Tags: reference-request, epsilon-delta

By cluttered  $\epsilon$, I refer to $C\epsilon$ "where $C$ is the constant $2/|b| + |2a/b^2|$" on p. 18 beneath. See the green arrows.

By unkempt $\delta$, I mean $\delta$'s like  [$\min(4\varepsilon -\varepsilon^2, 4\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768714/min-in-epsilon-delta#comment7755363_3768726), [$\log_2(\epsilon+4)-2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556253), [$\min\left[\dfrac1{2}, \dfrac{\epsilon}{e^{1.5}}\right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540551), [$\min\left(\dfrac1{2},\dfrac{\epsilon}{\dfrac{1}{2}+2|a|}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4354702), [$\min\left(1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(|a|^2+1)(2|a|+1)}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718194).

1. Most textbooks conclude $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs tidily with $\epsilon > 0$ alone, in red beneath. But what's the official term for this alternative $\delta-\epsilon$ proof that concludes $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs with a cluttered $\epsilon$,  in green beneath?
2. I forgot the particulars of another textbook (not the one beneath) that recommended the green alternative, because it's quicker to define a new $\epsilon_2 := \text{ cluttered } \epsilon_1$ at the end! Don't work backwards to deduce unkempt $\delta$'s. Please recommend more such textbooks?

[image]

Frank Morgan, *Real Analysis* (2005), pages 17-8.

Comment: What is a "cluttered, bedecked ϵ"?

Comment: And what is a "littered, garnished $\epsilon$"?

Comment: As one of my professors said, "It's the same amongst friends." There's no difference in the proofs, as small times a constant is still small.

Comment: And what is a "byzantine unkempt $\delta$"?

Comment: Flowery language is not something I get to see much of, now that I do maths most of the time - I like it

Comment: I don't know about other books, but I think folks who ever happen to need to do an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof do this sort of thing; you just check qualitatively that you could make the difference as small as you like by making $\delta$ small. So you start with $|x - x_0| < \delta$ for some $\delta$ and then check $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < C(\delta)$ where $C_{x_0}(\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$.The exception would be if you, for some reason, needed to actually get a quantitative bound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which textbook(s) advises to bound all inequalities with $\epsilon_0$ first, then end by defining $\epsilon = ...\epsilon_0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637704/which-textbooks-advises-to-bound-all-inequalities-with-epsilon-0-first-the)